# Setting DataGridView's Filter really slow, but only on the deployed application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Hey guys, I have an application used to mainly visualize data using some DataGridView I created using the designer a dataset object to which my **datagrids are automatically bound** (using some generated BindingSource objects), so I only care about filling the underlying tables in my initializing code:

```
TableAdapter1.Fill(DataSet.Table1)
TableAdapter2.Fill(DataSet.Table2)
```

after that I set a basic filter to the BindingSource objects to show only the most relevant data when I open the app, so I have the following code in my application:

```
' Fill tables
' Link the filled data

Table1BindingSource.Filter = GetBaseFilterTable1()
Table2BindingSource.Filter = GetBaseFilterTable2()
```

Now the filters are pretty simple and filter off using a couple of bit values in the rows **but** if setting the **first** filter in my dev environment **takes about 40ms** (using both Debug and Release compiling rules) when I try to **deploy** my application and open the deployed version I get around **15 seconds to complete the same instruction** (that I managed to find attaching the debugger to the deployed executable)

I really cannot wrap my mind around this problem have some of you already got stuck in something like this?

If you need some more information ask away, I'll be glad to provide you with what I have

**Edit**, I'm adding some information that I think might be relevant and that I've forgot, or something that was not clear from the comments:

- The application is deployed using click once.
- The data used in the dev environment is virtually the same data used by the deployed version
- The tests were all run on the same pc: mine

Comment: Maybe your dev project is working with an unrealistically small amount of data?

Comment: The data used by this application is small enough(-ish, the first table have 10k rows), so I usually can test everything using a copy of the data used in the deploy application.

Comment: This is `winforms` that works on someone's desktop. Where that desktop is located and how it is connected to your DB? Probably network-related delay. May be this is a laptop and issue is slow Wi-Fi? Have you looked into these potential bottlenecks?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the program works in my internal work network, the db is hosted on a server connected to the company network via ethernet, the same where the hosts that use the application are connected.
Also the different behavior showed on my pc, opening the deployed version of the program vs opening the built in visual studio one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a workaround for my problem and I managed to fix it, banally I set the Filter property before I link the datatables to my datagridviews

So the code it's now like this:

```
TableAdapter1.Fill(DataSet.Table1)
TableAdapter2.Fill(DataSet.Table2)

Table1BindingSource.Filter = GetBaseFilterTable1()
Table2BindingSource.Filter = GetBaseFilterTable2()

' This was moved down after setting the Filter Property
Table1BindingSource.DataSource = DataSet.Table1
Table2BindingSource.DataSource = DataSet.Table2
```

Instead of

```
TableAdapter1.Fill(DataSet.Table1)
TableAdapter2.Fill(DataSet.Table2)

Table1BindingSource.DataSource = DataSet.Table1
Table2BindingSource.DataSource = DataSet.Table2

Table1BindingSource.Filter = GetBaseFilterTable1()
Table2BindingSource.Filter = GetBaseFilterTable2()
```